# DC.js - Custom ordering of ordinal scale line chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Please forgive my english.

I am trying to create a line chart with ordinal scale and brushon function. I successfully set brushing on ordinal thanks to this method :
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/brush-ordinal.html
And now I need to set the x-axis values order.

My data is like this :

```
    [{"id_commune":4,"datation":"-30/-20","effectif":0.09,"commune":"Frejus","lieu_dit":"Les Aiguieres","departement":"83","pays":"FR","longitude":6.73703399,"latitude":43.433152,"quantite":1,"id_datation":1},
        {"id_commune":4,"datation":"-20/-10","effectif":0.09,"commune":"Frejus","lieu_dit":"Les Aiguieres","departement":"83","pays":"FR","longitude":6.73703399,"latitude":43.433152,"quantite":1,"id_datation":2},
        {"id_commune":4,"datation":"-10/1","effectif":0.09,"commune":"Frejus","lieu_dit":"Les Aiguieres","departement":"83","pays":"FR","longitude":6.73703399,"latitude":43.433152,"quantite":1,"id_datation":3},
    {"id_commune":7,"datation":"20/30","effectif":0.33,"commune":"Nimes","lieu_dit":"Solignac","departement":"30","pays":"FR","longitude":4.36005399,"latitude":43.836699,"quantite":1,"id_datation":6},{"id_commune":6,"datation":"20\/30","effectif":0.6,"commune":"Muralto","lieu_dit":"Liverpool b","departement":"TI","pays":"CH","longitude":8.80560809,"latitude":46.1729618,"quantite":1,"id_datation":6},
{"id_commune":4,"datation":"20/30","effectif":0.09,"commune":"Frejus","lieu_dit":"Les Aiguieres","departement":"83","pays":"FR","longitude":6.73703399,"latitude":43.433152,"quantite":1,"id_datation":6},{"id_commune":1,"datation":"20/30","effectif":0.14,"commune":"Aislingen","lieu_dit":"NP","departement":"Lkr. Dillingen an der Donau BY","pays":"DE","longitude":10.4559987,"latitude":48.5065603,"quantite":1,"id_datation":6},]
```

My crossfilter dimension and group look like this :

```
var ndx = crossfilter(records)
var graphDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.datation});
var graphGroup = graphDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.effectif;});
```

And the chart :

```
lineChart
            .width(950)
            .height(350)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 35, left: 30})
            .dimension(graphDim)            
            .keyAccessor(function(kv) { return  graphGroup.ord2int(kv.key); })
            .group(graphGroup)
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain(linear_domain))
            .xAxisLabel("Chronologie")
            .yAxisLabel("Effectif")
            .brushOn(true)
            .renderArea(true)
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
            .elasticY(true)
            .yAxis().ticks(4);
```

Right now, I get this :

[image: Graph]

The result I am trying to accomplish is the same chart but with x-axis ticks values ordered like this : 
"-30/-20
-20/-10
-10/1
..."

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions about the charting library. [dc] is a venerable Unix desktop calculator.

Comment: Sorry I did'nt know, I will be more carefull next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, it helps if you can include a reproducible example, for example a jsFiddle.

I understood what you were doing because I wrote the ordinal brushing example, but you didn't include all the code, so it wouldn't be clear to others.

Here is a [fiddle with complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0gjymovh/15/), and here is the relevant code:

```
var graphDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.datation});
var graphGroup = graphDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.effectif;});        
graphGroup = ordinal_to_linear_group(sort_group(graphGroup, function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.value, b.value);
    }));
    line = dc.lineChart('#line');
    var linear_domain = [-0.5, data.length - 0.5];
    line
        .width(950)
        .height(350)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 35, left: 30})
        .dimension(graphDim)            
        .keyAccessor(function(kv) { return  graphGroup.ord2int(kv.key); })
        .group(graphGroup)
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain(linear_domain))
        .xAxisLabel("Chronologie")
        .yAxisLabel("Effectif")
        .brushOn(true)
        .renderArea(true)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
        .elasticY(true)

    line.yAxis().ticks(4);

    line.xAxis()
        .tickValues(d3.range(data.length))
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return graphGroup.int2ord(d); });
```

Here is the (bad) result:

[image: bad result, sorted by descending value]

As its name implies, `sort_group()` creates a fake group sorted by the ordering function. Right now it's sorting by value, from highest to lowest:

```
sort_group(graphGroup, function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.value, b.value);
    })
```

It looks like you want to sort by the numeric value of the first part of each key. You can change the sort accordingly:

```
sort_group(graphGroup, function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(+a.key.split('/')[0], +b.key.split('/')[0]);
    })
```

This splits each key by `/`, then takes the first item (`[0]`), then converts it to a number (`+`), before using `d3.ascending` to specify sorting from low to high.

The result:

[image: sorting by first number, ascending]

And [a working version of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0gjymovh/21/).

Comment: Thank you so much !! I was starting to despair ! I will probably have more questions surrounding this kind of matter, but this issue was one of my worst.

Comment: That's great! When you receive an answer that works for you, please click the green checkmark next to the answer to accept it. This distributes some Fake Internet Points™ and it helps people track which questions still need answers.

Comment: It would seems I have to make progress on both DC and SO :)